# Find the time of occurrence of different peak value in different iterations

Tags: matlab, plot

I am looking for an expert opinion on `Matlab`, I am using following code to find the peak value of each iteration, but I cannot find the time of occurrence of each peak value.

Here is my function:

```
res_signal_example = EXAMPLE_runner_00_SingleBurst_S2S( )
value = max (res_signal_example.nRx_raw_matrix_wout_noise, [], [1 2])
```

Comment: Worst case, if you have the peak value, you can use arg = find(res_signal_example.nRx_raw_matrix_wout_noise, value). But please improve the question to clarify the dimensions of the entities involved and provide a minimal working example. Also, why saying you need an expert opinion? If you need a hint on doing your task you don't need an expert. If you had a very convoluted question regarding the "better way" to do something you have a solution in hand, then that could call for an expert, but you should really explain and justify what is needed from the hypothetical better solution.

Comment: I am sorry for asking expert opinion.by the way, here in nRx_raw_matrix_wout_noise result is store is in 3D array, 1*2000*111, here 2000 is the random number, each times i am sending, and get a peak value, so here i run my code for 111 times and take take a peak value of each times but problem is i cannot find the time of each peak.

Comment: SO here i have 111 peak values, and i need 111 times, which is the propagation delay of between my sender and receiver

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [second output of `max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#bubhhu5-1-I) to give you the index at which the maximum value occurred.

```
[value, position] = max (res_signal_example.nRx_raw_matrix_wout_noise, [], [1 2])
```

You could then use this `position` to index into a time array associated with the data to get the time at which the peak/maximum happened.

Note that if the maximum value occurred *more than once*, this will return only the first occurrence.